# Data vanishing from MariaDB / MySql after connection changes

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

After successfully loading data into MariaDB tables from Python and running validations, after a connection changes the data will be unavailable and tables look empty again.

E.g. I load data in the following manner from files that have been pulled to my local downloads

```
#load data into database  - note that this overwrites data and so has to be run in one chunk 

year_list = range(1995,2022)

filename1 = ["http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-{0}-part1.csv".format(year) for year in year_list]
filename2 =  ["http://prod.publicdata.landregistry.gov.uk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pp-{0}-part2.csv".format(year) for year in year_list] 
filenames= filename1 + filename2 


connection =   mysql.connector.connect( user=USR, password=PASSWORD, database=DBNAME,  host=ENDPOINT , port =PORT, allow_local_infile = True)
cursor = connection.cursor()


for url in filenames:
    name = url[-15:]
    query = "LOAD DATA local INFILE " + "'{}'".format(name)  + """ INTO TABLE property_prices.pp_data 
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                ENCLOSED BY ''
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'; """
    cursor.execute(query)
```

I then run validations e.g.

```
query = 'select * from property_prices.pp_data limit 5 '
cursor.execute(query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
print(records)


query = "select count(*) from pp_data ;"
cursor.execute(query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
print(records)

query = 'select year(date_of_transfer), count(*) from pp_data group by year(date_of_transfer);'
cursor.execute(query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
print(records)
```

And proceed to continue with loading another data table and running validations. After a certain amount of time, one of my queries will fail with 'mysql connection unavailable', and then when I look at previously loaded tables (e.g. running the validations again on pp_data) they return empty results - e.g. no results pulled, count = 0

Super frustrating, I thought it could be the database not rendering but even waiting a while and re-running validations with a fresh connection doesn't pull anything back

Comment: Are you certain the changes have been committed?  (I ask because I don’t see any `commit` statements, and you mention the data is ‘vanishing after a load’.)

Comment: damn, I thought it would be something simple, thank you!!!!! been losing my mind over this & none of the tutorials I looked at mentioned needing a commit...

Comment: Excellent.  Yes, commits are a standard database practice.